# How to store multiple roles in Role Claim?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, string.Join(",", user.UserRoles.Select(ur => ur.Role.Nome))));
```

However if i do this

```
User.IsInRole("myRole")
```

it returns false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this

```
Claim[] claims = new Claim[] 
{
          new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"),
          new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Dev"), 
          new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,"QA"),
          new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,"DBA")
};
```

Or you can use RoleManager for doing that. You can add roles by using role manager not by concatenating each role with comma using claim. But, before you use Role Manager, make sure you correctly register it in Startup.cs

**Startup.cs**

```
 services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole<string>>(options =>
             {
                 options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                 options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
                 options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                 options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                 options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;

                 options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

             })
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole<string>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>()
                .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole<string>>>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

And in db context, make sure you include IdentityRole or IdentityRole also.

**AppIdentityDbContext.cs (custom name)**

```
 public class AppIdentityDbContext:
        IdentityDbContext<AppUser,IdentityRole<string>,string>
    {
        public AppIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }
    }
```

To add role, you can specify in AccountController, or in other controllers you want. Make sure you use RoleManager. In this snippet of code, make sure you pay attention on Register action, you can see how to add new role there.

**AccountController.cs**

```
    public class AccountController : Controller
        {
            private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
            private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;
            private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole<string>> _roleManager;

            public AccountController(
                UserManager<AppUser> userManager,
                SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager,
                RoleManager<IdentityRole<string>> roleManager)
            {
                _userManager = userManager;
                _signInManager = signInManager;
                _roleManager = roleManager;
            }

            public IActionResult Register()
            {
                return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
            {
                if(ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    AppUser user = new AppUser
                    {
                        FullName = model.FullName,
                        Email = model.Email,
                        UserName = model.Email
                    };
                    var createResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                    if(createResult.Succeeded)
                    {
                        await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim("sys:FullName", model.FullName));
                        if(!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("User"))
                        {
                            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("User"));
                        }
if(!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Dev"))
                        {
                            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Dev"));
                        }
                        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User");
                        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Dev");
                        string token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                        string url = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new
                        {
                            email = model.Email,
                            token
                        }, Request.Scheme);
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("ConfirmEmail.txt", url);
                        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Confirmation), new
                        {
                            confirmation = ConfirmationStatus.EmailConfirmation
                        });
                    }
                    foreach(var error in createResult.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                    }
                }

                return View(model);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks the first option is what i was looking for. I'm not using Identity yet on my company but it is something to consider in future when I learn to customize it better to my needs

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I solved that:

```
private async Task<List<Claim>> GetClaims(User user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();

        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }

        return claims;
    }
```